# Net Core Website crashes immediately with code 0xe0434352

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

Im having an issue where our ASP Net Core Website crashes immediately with little information.

The output in visual studio shows:
`The program '[10196] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).`

After settings `COREHOST_TRACE = 1`, I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject.dll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. File is corrupt. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013110E) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: File is corrupt. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013110E)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The Event viewer shows me the same error and says the source is `.NET Runtime`, and is then immediatly followed by another error with the source `Applciation Error`, with the following details:

> Faulting application name: dotnet.exe, version: 5.0.721.25508, time stamp: 0x609308e9
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0x924f9cdb
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
> Fault offset: 0x0000000000034b89
> Faulting process id: 0x4a18
> Faulting application start time: 0x01d76797eececb6d
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
> Report Id: eed8cc7d-eeb1-45d0-b33c-532e3524f4ee
> Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Genuinely, I have no idea why, but this is being caused when I add any new property to any class, if I remove it, clean the project, rebuild and run, it works as expected.

I can't find any helpful information anywhere, suggestions on how I can get the real error that is causing the crash would be much appreciated.

Comment: For the error `System.BadImageFormatException`,maybe you can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-5.0).